# Creating a sequential flow thru an ASP.Net MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I have a view "step one" that has a form with a field and I submit/post that form to my HttpPost action I retrieve a data set based on that input form. If I get the results back I populate a new model and pass that to my "step two" view `return View("StepTwo",newmodel)`
which then brings up the new view showing all the fields from the newmodel. When I submit this second form I get pushed back to the initial "Step One" view and action. 
What I really want to do is submit "step two" to a step two post action.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change where the form is posting to by using something like:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post)){
    //Form code goes here
}
```

This is just a guess, however. More code would help.